# Creating a new AD LDS instance without the Setup Wizard?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, scripting, windows-command-prompt, ad-lds

Is the installation of a new unique instance of AD LDS (using either cmd or PowerShell) possible? All resources I can find online just use the Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services Setup Wizard.

PowerShell has the Active Directory Module for working with *existing* LDS instances but I have not found a way that it can be used for creating a new instance of AD LDS.

Comment: Microsoft's documentation states that you can use Powershell's _Active Directory Module_ to work with LDS instances. Please [edit] the question to explain what do you have troubles with.

Comment: Thank you @JosefZ, I have edited the question. I have not seen a way to create new instances of AD LDS with that module, which is the task I am asking about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the "secret sauce" is a command called AdamInstall.exe, which can be run to perform unattended instance setups. You can run AdamInstall.exe on Server Core. Begin by creating this answer text file.

```
[ADAMInstall]
InstallType=Unique
InstanceName=InstanceName
LocalLDAPPortToListenOn=PortNumiber
LocalSSLPortToListenOn=PortNumiber
NewApplicationPartitionToCreate=PartitionName
DataFilesPath=D:\ADAMInstances\InstanceName\Data
LogFilesPath=D:\ADAMInstances\InstanceName\Data
ServiceAccount=DomainorMachineName\AccountName
ServicePassword=Password
Administrator=Domain\GroupName
ImportLDIFFiles="LDIFFilename1" "LDIFFilename2" "LDIFFilename3" 
SourceUserName=DomainorMachineName\AccountName SourcePassword=Password“
```

Comment: Since this uses Server Core, is this not usable on Windows 10 Pro?

Comment: it should be available on windows 10 but I've not tested it there.

Comment: It looks like it is! Also, in case it's helpful to others: The full path to the executable is `C:\Windows\ADAM\adaminstall.exe` and if you run the command `C:\Windows\ADAM\adaminstall.exe /?:answer` it will give you a full description of all possible parameters that can be included in the `answer.txt` file.